# What species of light green shrub is this?

Tags: identification, shrubs

This is a wonderful bush! I would love to plant more of them. But I have no idea what it's called. This individual is 3 years old, 30 inches high, and has 3 inch long leaves. It's currently blooming in purple flowers in New Jersey.

[image: bush]
[image: bush2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *Spiraea japonica*, most likely the variety *'Goldmound'*. There are one or two other varieties with yellow leaves such as *'Magic Carpet*' and *'Goldflame'* which has primarily yellow leaves but with some pink and paler variegation.

Comment: Thanks, that's great info!